# C strange array allocation behavior

Tags: c, memory-management

I use xcode with c and I have a strange problem with the following code.

When the algorithm reaches the y[k] = 0.0 row in my conv function then the x array filled by 0-s, I must understand why, I already correct this error in my own way. 
The problem is not appear when I comment the second row and uncomment the third row in main function(see below). I know that I reallocate the array in generateSquareSignal, but this is not a reason for this bug I think.

```
 int length = 100;
 double *output = (double*) malloc(10 * length * sizeof(double));
 //double *output;
 output = generateSquareSignal(length);
 double *input1 = (double*) malloc(length * sizeof(double));
 double *input2 = (double*) malloc(length * sizeof(double));

 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        input2[i] = output[i];
        input1[i] = output[i];
                //printf("-%d=%lf\n",i ,input1[i]);
 }

 conv(input1, length, input2, length, output, 2 * length );


double* generateSquareSignal(int length) {

  printf("double* generateSquareSignal(int length)\n");

  double *signal = (double*) malloc(length * sizeof(double));

  int length_period = length / kPeriodSignal;
  for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i % (length_period) < (length_period / 2)) {
        signal[i] = 1.0;
    } else {
        signal[i] = -1.0;
    }
    //printf("%d. - %lf\n", i, signal[i]);
 }

 return signal;
}



void conv( double *x,  int N_signal,
                         double *h, int N_kernel,
                         double *y, int N_output) {
int k;
for(k = 0; k < N_signal + N_kernel; k++) {
    y[k] = 0.0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N_signal; i++) {
    printf("%lf-%lf\n", x[i], y[i]);
}


for(int i = 0; i < N_signal; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N_kernel; j++) {
        double  xx = x[i];
        double  hh = h[j];
        double  yy = y[i + j];
        y[i + j] += x[i] * h[j];
        //printf("=%lf\n", y[i + j]);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: don't cast the return of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this part of your code (with added line numbers)

```
 1 int length = 100;
 2 double *output = (double*) malloc(10 * length * sizeof(double));
 3 //double *output;
 4 output = generateSquareSignal(length);
 /* ... snipped line 5 to 12 */
13
14 conv(input1, length, input2, length, output, 2 * length );
```

In line 2, you allocate memory to hold 1000 doubles.

In line 4, you overwrite the only reference you had to that memory with a reference to a buffer that holds 100 doubles. This creates a memory leak of the memory allocated in line 2.

In line 14, you tell the `conv` function that the variable `output` (which becomes `y` inside `conv`) can store 200 doubles (and `conv` implicitly presumes it can store at least that amount of data in there). This is not true as it actually refers to a block of 100 doubles. The result is that `conv` writes outside of the bounds of the buffer referred to by `output` and `y`, which causes undefined behaviour.
In your case, the undefined behaviour happens to be that the spill-over ends up in the memory block that was allocated next, which is the one referred to by `input1` and `x`.

In the end, the root-cause for the bug is indeed the new allocation made in `generateSquareSignal` that overwrites the previous allocation for `output`.

Answer (score 3):

You set output to point to malloced array with size of length. Then you use it beyond that. Result is pretty random... The malloc for 10*length does nothing (except leak memory) because you overwrite it's return value on the next line with return value of generateSquareSignal...

Comment: I know that I cause memory leak with this malloc, but why I get an array which filled by 0 in another function? thanks for your answer

Comment: Possible when the program return from the generateSquare signal free up the signal variable?

Comment: Another answer tells more about what probably happens in this particular code, but the important point is, if you have buffer overrun (meaning: write to memory after the end of allocated block, outside of it, corrupting whatever else happens to be there), result is "random", undefined, maybe a quick crash if you are *lucky*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of issues here... but most of them are style. The real problem is just the fact that you have a memory leak and that's causing your problem. If you're going to make a function that allocates memory, let it allocate the memory:

```
double *output = (double*) malloc(10 * length * sizeof(double));
output = generateSquareSignal(length);
```

Changeing these two lines of code like this:

```
double *output;
output = generateSquareSignal(10 * length);
```

Will eliminate that memory leak, and will allow your code to be properly sized as you wish (an array big enough for 1000 doubles)

---

Just for fun, here's a few of the other points I'm thinking of:

1. why do you need room for 1000 doubles when you're only storing 200 in there?
2. `length` appears to be a constant, you can make it a global #define and then you don't have to worry about passing it around
3. If you are going to pass length, you don't need to pass it twice to `conv()` because it's the same for `input` arrays
4. You can eliminate your need to set `y` in the `conv()` loop by just memseting the first 200 spots to `0.0`

Comment: thanks for your answer and observation, I know that the problems come from the memory leak but how can it is possible a leak can't cause this kind of error just remains some garbage in memory.

Comment: @flatronka - you're correct, the leak isn't the cause, but you'll note my fix changed two things, the leak, and the size that is being allocated from `generateSquareSignal()`. Before it was `100*sizeof(double)`, then the `conv()` function was expecting it to be at least `200 * sizeof(double)`, so you were overflowing your array and it was causing the problems there.